# How to restrict the number of consumer groups to one per topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to restrict the number of consumer groups to max one per topic created in kafka.Is there a way how i can limit the number of groups to just one?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The idea to control the number of consumer groups "conflicts" with the overall design idea of Kafka to decouple producers and consumers and to allow N independent consumers for the same topics.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

And it's questionable why you want to do this in the first place?